# regex to find all import * from * in a string

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a string of a code file generated by svelte and I would like to write a regex to find all  non local import statements, remove them and replace them with some other code.

Generated code:

```
/* generated by Svelte v3.31.2 */
// want to get this one
import {
    SvelteComponent,
} from "svelte/internal";

// want to leave this one
import Button from "Button.svelte";

class Component extends SvelteComponent {
    constructor(options) {
        super();
        if (!document.getElementById("svelte-1vakd91-style")) add_css();
        init(this, options, null, create_fragment, safe_not_equal, {});
    }
}

export default Component;
```

Comment: Right and what have you tried?

Comment: I've looked into this package: https://github.com/cheton/find-imports/blob/master/index.js and this one: https://gist.github.com/manekinekko/7e58a17bc62a9be47172 but I'm not very good with regex... which is why I'm asking the question... I would like some help :)

Comment: Actually I think the gist I linked to could be very good but I don't know how to tailor it to my needs.

Comment: Don't use regex for this, but a proper tool for the job. Transpilers were built to solve the problem, and they will properly parse javascript.

Comment: Thanks for the input Bergi!

Comment: Bergi actually made a really good point here that I had overlooked. I am already using Babel standalone and I tried looking for a plugin to do what I wanted but I really wasn't confident writing one myself, then I found this amazing article https://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/replacing-code-for-production-with-babel-transformation and decided to write my own babel plugin. Simple, elegant solution. Thanks again for the tip Bergi!

Answer (score 1):

`/import {?(\s{0,}((?!\d)(\w+)((:\w+)?,?)|(\s{0,}\*)(as\s{0,}\w+)?))+}? from ('|")(?!(\.|\/))(?!\d)(\w+(\/){0,})+('|")/gi`

Basically this says match any set of strings that:

has `import` followed by...

`{?(\s{0,}((?!\d)(\w+)((:\w+)?,?)|(\s{0,}\*)(as\s{0,}\w+)?))+}?`

...any character that's a letter, number, or _ that DOES NOT start with a number or it equals to an `*` that is optionally wrapped in curly brackets. It also makes sure to catch aliases with either `:` followed by any letters or numbers or an `as` followed by any letters or numbers

`from ('|")(?!(\.|\/))(?!\d)(\w+(\/){0,})+('|")`

This says that it's also followed by a `from` and matches any letters or numbers that DOES NOT start with a `.` or `/` because if it starts with that it's importing something from your own directory and not the node modules. However that can freely be followed by a `/` after a letter or number because it's accessing a specific file or folder in the node modules.

Note: This works for import export. Not require.

Comment: Thanks for the response and explanation Destroyer22719 (Epic Name by the way!)!! I'll try this out and get back to you.